# How to recompile linux kernel and make an iso installation for ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, server, kernel, firmware

I want to install Ubuntu server 14.04.3 on a my server which has an ***intel PCI-E* 10 Gigabit*** network card.

The installation wizard does not detect this network since the firmware is not available on the kernel installed.

My question is how to make my own installation **iso** for **ubuntu 14.04.3 server** so that i can *recompile the kernel and add the firmware*.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you install Ubuntu first and the compile the kernel? You could get the source code in your computer through an external drive.

Comment: it sounds interesting can you explain more ?

Comment: So you need to compile a custom kernel with custom drives/modules, right? You could install Ubuntu on your machine, get the kernel source code from another machine through an external storgae device and then compile/install the new kernel on your Ubuntu Server so it recognizes your network card.